# How to correctly detect the meta key with a QKeyEvent?

Tags: qt

I'm trying to implement a shortcut handler with Qt to allow the user to edit them. I want it to be interactive so I'm displaying the shortcut as the is currently typing, not only when finished. I think I'm not that far from the solution but I still have some issues with the meta key (Windows key on Windows).

It seems to be detected by the first if statement below but not by the one in the end, using the modifiers function.

```
void ShortcutInputWidget::handleKeyEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    int keyDisplayed = event->key();
    Qt::Key keys = static_cast<Qt::Key>(keyDisplayed);

    // if the key pressed is only a modifier, we reset the key
    if(keys == Qt::Key_Control ||
        keys == Qt::Key_Shift ||
        keys == Qt::Key_Alt ||
        keys == Qt::Key_Meta)
    { 
        qDebug() << "Single press of special key: Ctrl, Shift, Alt or Meta";
        if (keys == Qt::Key_Meta)
            qDebug() << "meta: " << QKeySequence(Qt::META);
        keyDisplayed = 0;
    }

    // handle modifiers
    Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifiers = event->modifiers();
    QString text = event->text();
    qDebug() << text;
    if (modifiers & Qt::ShiftModifier){
        keyDisplayed |= Qt::SHIFT;
        qDebug() << "shift modifier detected";
    }
    if (modifiers & Qt::ControlModifier){
        keyDisplayed |= Qt::CTRL;
        qDebug() << "control modifier detected";
    }
    if (modifiers & Qt::MetaModifier){
        keyDisplayed |= Qt::META;
        qDebug() << "meta detected";
    }
    if (modifiers & Qt::AltModifier){
        keyDisplayed |= Qt::ALT;
        qDebug() << "alt modifier detected";
    }

    qDebug() << QKeySequence(keyDisplayed);
    setText(QKeySequence(keyDisplayed));
    event->accept();
}
```

The output if I hit only the meta key is `meta: QKeySequence("Meta+")` but no `meta detected`. But if I hit "ctrl + meta" the meta key is detected by both statements.

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm using Windows 7 and I have an EN-GB keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that on Windows the Windows key is not a ***modifier***. When you debug or print the value obtained by

```
 Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifiers = event->modifiers();
```

you obtain an empty flag when pressing the windows keys, but a non empty flag for the other keys you handle... I think it make sense, because in my experience **on windows** the windows key is never used *by user applications*.

Now the Mac Key is a modifier by default on Mac OSes, and the windows key is assigned to this key when running windows on Mac computer. This becomes really tricky as it can be a valid modifier when running OS X and not valid when running Windows.

The only advice I can give is to think again about what you want to achieve, and then test on Mac, Windows, and Linux separately. Sometimes it is necessary to ensure portability.

Comment: yes, maybe you're right, what I thought was a bug may actually not be. I will be careful and test on Mac as well.

Comment: It should be noted that there are actually quite a few shortcut keys that are WindowsKey+<key> (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449)

Comment: Thanks Chris... Do you know if these shortcut keys are "locked" or can be handled in general?

Answer (score 0):

Well I run the same sample On Linux[Qt creator]. It worked perfectly, both messages were displayed. Might be some OS related issue in your case. The key I pressed was windows key which it detected as meta key.

```
Single press of special key: Ctrl, Shift, Alt or Meta 
meta:  QKeySequence("Meta+") 
"" 
meta detected 
QKeySequence("Meta+")
```